# Font Type Delphi in DebenuPDFLibraryLite1114

Tags: delphi, pdf

I'm making a small program which is added to a PDF and created an image and some text. The problem is that using the function `AddTrueTypeFont` gives me errors either `Invalid Variant Error` or `You can not use this statement in an automatic object`.

I am using the [Debenu Quick PDF Library](http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/), Lite version 1114 (DebenuPDFLibraryLite1114.dll).

In summary, I would like to know how I can put a text with font Verdana in the source.

Comment: Please ask better questions. I know this is a language barrier, but you cannot "add a program to a PDF", and I doubt that you want to "put a text with font Verdana in the source" code. I cleaned up as far as I could but you need to [edit] your question further. And adding the relevant code (properly indented with 4 spaces) is definitely required!

Comment: And [they have a forum](http://forums.debenu.com/debenu-quick-pdf-library_forum7.html)

Comment: I'm adding test and images to an existing PDF with the library Quick Debenu (Lite) and I am using Delphi. My problem is that i cant use AddTrueTypeFont,

Comment: What is AddTrueTypeFont supposed to do - add a font into the PDF, or set the font of some text in the PDF? Again, **edit your question and show some code**.

Comment: AddTrueTypeFont is used to set the font on PDF. I will show the code Monday, because i dont have it right now.